# Nifi ConvertAvroToORC processor can't convert avro file which has array which consists of floats and array of float

Tags: avro, apache-nifi, orc

1. I have the avro scheme (pay attention on nested array struct):

```
{
   "namespace":"nifi",
   "name":"scheme_name",
   "type":"record",
   "fields":[
        {
          "name":"values",
          "type":{
             "type":"array",
             "items":{
                "type":"array",
                "items": ["float", {"type": "array", "items": ["float", "string", "null"]}]
             }
          }
       }
   ]
}
```

2. I have the json file:

```
{"values": [[1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, [-1, -1.1, -1.2, -1.3], -2, 3], [2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, [-2, -2.1, -2.2, -2.3], -3, 4]]}
```

3. I have next nifi processor group (see picture). GetFile - just get json which you can see above. ConvertRecord - just convert recieved json by JsonTreeReader to avro by AvroRecordSetWriter. JsonTreeReader and AvroRecordSetWriter have schema registry: AvroSchemaRegistry (which contain avro scheme which you can see above).
   [image: Nifi_process]

On the step converting avro to orc nifi throws exception:

```java
2018-10-17 13:51:56,809 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] o.a.n.processors.hive.ConvertAvroToORC ConvertAvroToORC[id=814f08dc-0166-1000-a46c-f69042e8ae94] ConvertAvroToORC[id=814f08dc-0166-1000-a46c-f69042e8ae94] failed to process session due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object Type for class org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Array not in Union declaration; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object Type for class org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Array not in Union declaration
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object Type for class org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Array not in Union declaration
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.NiFiOrcUtils.convertToORCObject(NiFiOrcUtils.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.NiFiOrcUtils.lambda$convertToORCObject$7(NiFiOrcUtils.java:149)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.NiFiOrcUtils.convertToORCObject(NiFiOrcUtils.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.NiFiOrcUtils.lambda$convertToORCObject$7(NiFiOrcUtils.java:149)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.NiFiOrcUtils.convertToORCObject(NiFiOrcUtils.java:149)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.ConvertAvroToORC.lambda$onTrigger$0(ConvertAvroToORC.java:245)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.write(StandardProcessSession.java:2885)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.ConvertAvroToORC.onTrigger(ConvertAvroToORC.java:209)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1165)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:203)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-10-17 13:51:56,812 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] o.a.n.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask Administratively Yielding ConvertAvroToORC[id=814f08dc-0166-1000-a46c-f69042e8ae94] due to uncaught Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object Type for class org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Array not in Union declaration
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object Type for class org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Array not in Union declaration
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.NiFiOrcUtils.convertToORCObject(NiFiOrcUtils.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.NiFiOrcUtils.lambda$convertToORCObject$7(NiFiOrcUtils.java:149)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.NiFiOrcUtils.convertToORCObject(NiFiOrcUtils.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.NiFiOrcUtils.lambda$convertToORCObject$7(NiFiOrcUtils.java:149)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.NiFiOrcUtils.convertToORCObject(NiFiOrcUtils.java:149)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.ConvertAvroToORC.lambda$onTrigger$0(ConvertAvroToORC.java:245)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.write(StandardProcessSession.java:2885)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.ConvertAvroToORC.onTrigger(ConvertAvroToORC.java:209)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1165)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:203)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-10-17 13:52:01,247 INFO [NiFi Web Server-214] o.a.n.c.s.StandardProcessScheduler Stopping ConvertRecord[id=814a4abe-0166-1000-0755-4d43aef3dc4a]
2018-10-17 13:52:01,247 INFO [NiFi Web Server-214] o.a.n.controller.StandardProcessorNode Stopping processor: class org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertRecord
2018-10-17 13:52:01,247 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Stopped scheduling ConvertRecord[id=814a4abe-0166-1000-0755-4d43aef3dc4a] to run
```

So, please tell me where am I wrong?

Environment: 
OS:SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3 (release 12.3) 
or Windows 7 Corporate SP1 
Nifi version: 1.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug about this in jira:
[NIFI-5716. ConvertAvroToORC processor can't convert avro file which has array which consists of floats and array of float](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NIFI/issues/NIFI-5716?filter=allopenissues)